# xpath to access different links which xml,html,pdf as linktext

Tags: selenium-webdriver

- When I search with input a -- the page displays me a link with linktest html.
- When I search with input b -- the page displays me a link with linktest xml.
- When I search with input c -- the page displays me a link with linktest pdf.

I have different linktests for different inputs

on locating the link element, the xpath shows

```
//*[contains(text(),'html')]
//*[contains(text(),'xml')]
//*[contains(text(),'pdf')]
```

I need generic xpath. Tried `by.tagName("a")` any other way other than preceeding and following logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical expressions in xpath, like `and` or `or`. So to match an element with text: pdf, html or xml you could use a following exception:

```
//a[contains(text(),'html') or contains(text(),'xml') or contains(text(),'pdf')]
```

Comment: I have 48 such types,may be in future some more may be added.

Comment: @zaki Based on the question I though that there are only those 3 you have mentionded. In case of 48 it would be good from you to share the HTML source as of the links to see if we have other possibilities for a generic expression.